# Adding list items to the end of items in another list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have:

```
foo = ['/directory/1/', '/directory/2']
bar = ['1.txt', '2.txt']
```

I want:

```
faa = ['/directory/1/1.txt', '/directory/2/2.txt']
```

I can only seem to call operations that are trying to add strings to lists which result in a type error.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> [os.path.join(a, b) for a, b in zip(foo, bar)]
['/directory/1/1.txt', '/directory/2/2.txt']
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a one liner that uses list comprehension:

```
faa = ['/'.join(b).replace('//', '/') for b in zip(foo, bar)]
```

Note that this will always use forward slashes (/) while concatenating, while @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' solution is more cross platform (it will use backslashes when run in Windows, for example) if you are after it.

Comment: Please don't encourage this `.replace('//', '/')` when working with paths.

Comment: It is not certain that they are paths. The OP might want to stick to forward slashes instead of being platform specific.

Answer (score 0):

To join two strings, you just add them.

```
>>> foo = ['/directory/1/', '/directory/2/']
>>> bar = ['1.txt', '2.txt']
>>> map(lambda x,y:x+y, foo, bar)
['/directory/1/1.txt', '/directory/2/2.txt']
```

...assuming that your original list has a typo and `'/directory/2'` should be `'/directory/2/'`

Essentially, this creates a function (lambda) on the fly that will return the sum of its two arguments and applies it to every element of the pair of lists in parallel.

Links to documentation for [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) & 
[lambda](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this one. Don't make complicate.

```
faa = [x+y for x, y in zip(foo, bar)]
```

The output will be

```
    >>> faa
    ['/directory/1/1.txt', '/directory/2/2.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for lists in zip(foo,bar):
  together.insert(1,'/'.join(lists).replace('//','/'))

print together

together2 = map("{0[0]}{0[1]}".format, zip(foo,bar))
print together2
```

The second one will work only if the list get changed to

```
foo =  ['/directory/1/', '/directory/2/']
bar = ['1.txt', '2.txt']
```

Because the second method doesn't add the '/ ' in the end of items of the first list...Happy to help anyway...

New to Stackoverflow btw